SailPoint FAM ElasticSearch8.2 Installation on SailPoint FAM 8.3 SP4
We have SailPoint FAM 8.3 SP4 environment setup and we do have Elastic Serach 5.xx version to support 8.3 SP4 which is working fine. But we are planning to do SailPoint FAM Upgrade to 8.4 and to support this upgrade, we were trying to install latest version of Elasticsearch 8.2 as a prerequisite for the upgrade, but the installation is failing.
One thing we found from log is that Elasticsearch registry key not found in registry and also while installing it didn't ask us to provide any specific credential also. Can someone help us here, so that we can complete this config successfully?
